# How can i make an if statement that reacts to the contents of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a tik tak toe game and I am struggling making an alert for when someone wins the game. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/tv_dinner123/7uft0b5s/1/) is a JSFiddle for what id have made so far, not including anything about the alert for when someone wins.

My plan is to make if statements for each possible way someone could win (there are only 8). I want to do this by creating the following type of code, but I don't know how.

This is not actual code, but it is the English version of what i want to accomplish.

```
if(HTML element id="topLeft" displays "X" && HTML element id="topCenter" displays "X" && HTML element id="topRight" displays "X"){
alert(Player X has won);
}
```

I tried accomplishing this with this code (this is my attempt at writing actual javascript code)

```
if(document.getElementById("bottomRight").innerHTML=="X"){
    alert("X");
}
```

I can kind of see why this is incorrect, but not really. I know what i'm trying to accomplish, but I don't know how to do it in the javascript language. I'm trying to make an if statement for when an html element displays a specific text. In the case of tik tak toe, it is either "X" or "O". I don't know for sure if this is even possible, but I immagine it is. I'm aware that there is probably a more eficient way to do this, however, I am fairly new to coding. I am open to hearing alternate solutions, but keep in mind that they will go over my head if they are overly complex. Thanks for reading, and thanks for your help.

Comment: What you need to think about is events.  For example, if the user clicks in a square, that makes the browser fire an onClick event.  You attach a JavaScript function to that event and have it update things based on it.  Your code needs to run when the user does something to change the world.  (You also probably need some code that runs right away to set the initial state of things.)  See the moz docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

From context of your question, I understood that you are trying to observe a change in HTML. If that's correct, then JavaScript provides a good solution for your struggle. [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById('game-board');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver*

Although, I suggest you to think of a different solution using arrays and create event-driven app, where each click has the same callback function and checks whether the element in array should be changed. Once you've done that, within the same callback function you could create a condition if player moves are winning one.

Comment: Cool idea. Although I think using this API adds an extra layer of complexity the OP may not need.  (And I think technically this interface is provided by the browsers instead of by JavaScript itself -- but this may be more subtle a distinction than the OP cares about.)

Comment: You are 100% correct, it's actually a DOM specification, not ECMA. I wanted to simplify this one for OP :)

Answer (score 0):

I have added some pointers, the evaluate function. Not sure if this is what you want or is simple enough for you to follow. But take a look

```
//New helper function
function evaluate() {
      if(document.getElementById("bottomRight").innerHTML=="X"){
          alert("X");
      }
    }


let topLeftClicked=false;
// YOUR ORIGINAL CODE ....

function bottomRight(){
    if(!bottomRightClicked){
        bottomRightClicked=true;
        document.getElementById("bottomRight").innerHTML=
        XorO;
        XtoO();
    }
// Calling evaluate
        evaluate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised and enhanced version of the code from your fiddle. The `handleSquareClick` function is the main listener, but `getWinnerIfAny` and `getTextIfThreeMatch` handle a lot of the win-assessment logic you were struggling with.

Read over the in-code comments to see what the script does in detail.

```js
//
// Identifies some DOM elements
//
const board = document.getElementsByClassName("board")[0];
const squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");



//
// Sets up the 8 "winning" groups of 3 squares each (row, columns, and diagonals) 
//

// Hard codes group names to match the HTML class names -- (It would be smarter to make 
//   ONE canonical set of names, then DERIVE the other set of names, but I was lazy.)
const groupNames = ["top","middle","bottom","left","center","right","downDiag","upDiag"];

// Binds an arrow function to the name `makeGroup`. The function will take a group name
//   and return an array containing the 3 DOM squares that have a corresponding class name
const makeGroup = (groupName) => 
  Array.from(squares).filter(square => square.classList.contains(groupName));

// Defines an array of arrays: the 8 "winning" groups of squares (one for each group name)
const groups = groupNames.map(groupName => makeGroup(groupName));



//
// Sets up a function that can toggle between X and O
//

// The `makeFunctionToToggleCharacters` function returns a new function,
//   which gets bound to the name `toggleChar` and will always return "X" or "O"
const toggleChar = makeFunctionToToggleCharacters();



//
// An event listener (named handleSquareClick) will respond to user actions
//
//  It directly relies on:
//    isEmptySquare - assesses relavence of click
//    toggleChar        - chooses X or O
//    getStatus         - checks whether game is over
//    handleGameEnd - stops UI and announces winner
//
//  With addtional help from:
//    getWinnerIfAny            - explores winning groups
//    getTextIfThreeMatch - compares squares in a group
//    allSquaresFull            - notices drawn games
//  

// Calls `handleSquareClick` whenever user clicks anything within the board
board.addEventListener("click", handleSquareClick);

// Defines our click listener
function handleSquareClick(event){ // Listeners can access triggering events
  const clickee = event.target; // Event has a useful "target" property
  if(!isEmptySquare(clickee)){ return; } // Ignores irrelevant clicks
  clickee.innerHTML = toggleChar(); // Updates to X or O, and writes it to the DOM

  // Calls `getStatus` to check for end of game (win or draw)
  const statusText = getStatus();

  // Calls `handleGameEnd` if game is over
  if(statusText !== "playing"){
    handleGameEnd(statusText);
  }
  // Else, we're still playing, so the page just waits for another click
}

function isEmptySquare(element){
  // Returns true if the clicked element is an empty square
  return element.classList.contains("square") && element.innerHTML === "";
}

function getStatus(){
  // Defines, updates, and returns a statusText string
  // (Uses getWinnerIfAny and allSquaresFull to make updates)

  let statusText = "playing";

  // Calls getWinnerIfAny, and possibly updates statusText
  const winner = getWinnerIfAny(Array.from(squares));
  if(winner != ""){
    statusText = `${winner} wins!`;
  }

  // Calls allSquaresFull, and possibly updates statusText
  else if(allSquaresFull(Array.from(squares)) === true){
    statusText = "Drawn game";
  }
  // Returns the text to the function that called getStatus (the click listener)
  return statusText;
}


function getWinnerIfAny(){
  // Loops through the "winnable" groups, destructuring each group into 3 separate
  //   "member" squares, which are all passed as arguments into `getTextIfThreeMatch`
  // If all 3 members of any group contain identical text, returns that text (which
  //   will be"X" or "O"), and stops looping
  // (If no group's members all contain identical text, returns the empty string)
  for ([memberA, memberB, memberC] of groups){ // This uses "array destructutring"
    const winner = getTextIfThreeMatch(memberA, memberB, memberC)
    if(winner != ""){
      return winner; // Breaks out of loop early if a winner is found
    }
  }
  return ""; // Returns empty string by default
}

function getTextIfThreeMatch(squareA, squareB, squareC){
  // Given 3 squares, if they have the same (non-empty) textContent, returns that text
  // Else, returns the empty string
  const
    textA = squareA.textContent,
    textB = squareB.textContent,
    textC = squareC.textContent;
  if((textA != "") && (textB === textA) && (textC === textA)){
    return textA;
  }
  else{
    return "";
  }
}

function handleGameEnd(status){
  // Stops responding to clicks, and updates the display
  board.removeEventListener("click", handleSquareClick);
  board.classList.add("done");
  console.log(status);
}

function allSquaresFull(arrayOfSquares){
  // Returns true if no legal moves are left
  // (Note: this doesn't always mean a draw, b/c X can win on the last move)
  return !arrayOfSquares.some(
    square => isEmptySquare(square)
  );
}



//
// Defines the function that creates the character-toggling function used above
//
function makeFunctionToToggleCharacters(){
  let char; // "char" only exists in this context (and starts undefined)

  // nextCharFunc is a closure -- it can access this context later
  function nextCharFunc(){
    if (char === "X"){ char = "O"; }
    else{ char = "X"; }  // default output will be "X" (defines char if necessary)
    return char;
  }

  // The returned function will be the only way to access "char" later
  return nextCharFunc;
}
```

```css
.board { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 20px 20px 20px; }
.square { font-size: 1.2em; height: 1.2em; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 1px solid gray; }
.done .square { background-color: rosybrown; }
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <p class="square top left downDiag"></p>
  <p class="square top center"></p>
  <p class="square top right upDiag" data-row="top"></p>
  <p class="square middle left"></p>
  <p class="square middle center downDiag upDiag"></p>
  <p class="square middle right"></p>
  <p class="square bottom left upDiag"></p>
  <p class="square bottom center"></p>
  <p class="square bottom right downDiag"></p>
</div>
```